# Simplifying radicals without using prime factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Is there an easy way to simplify radicals?

For example, take the case of $\sqrt{252}$.  We can the find prime factorization of $252$ as $252=2\times 2\times 3 \times 3\times 7$ and thus we get $\sqrt{252}=\sqrt{2\times 2\times 3 \times 3\times 7}=6\sqrt{7}.$

This method takes more time for large numbers. Without doing these calculations, i.e., without finding out prime factorization, is there any approach available to simplify radicals?

Please help. thanks.

Comment: For this kind of simplification, not really, I think. If all you're after is $15.87$, then there are numerous methods (not that I personally know very many, but I know they are there).

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: If the number if definable as a multiple of some perfect square factors, that would mean the radical is reducible.For example:$252=16^2-2^2=(16-2)(16+2)=2^2.3^2.7$. I think this takes shorter time than  factorizing.

Comment: If the number is too large to complete the factorization, you cannot do any better than factor the number as far as possible. If you continue upto, lets say, $10^6$, chances that the cofactor is squarefree, are very good. In most cases, you will not miss a better solution, but only the factorization makes all doubts vanish.

Comment: @sirous But in general, deciding whether a number is squarefree is not significantly easier than factoring.